# Was This Robot able to feel his arm being sawed off?

Tags: movie, chappie

The movie **Chappie** Is mostly about this robot (or more specifically AI) that can think for itself. Chappie (the main robot protagonist) is very cute, and has a very quick way of learning, anyways later in the movie there is this scene where two of his owners drove hi  into the middle of a zone hostile to police robots (Chappie is fashioned as one) and he gets attacked by fire bombs, pipes, etc. He eventually gets kidnapped by this man who wants a piece of him and he has four men hold chappie down while he does this and he saws off his arm, a little bit after this chappie baisically flings everyone off him, and jumps out of the moving truck. Now there are two main evidinces that I have noticed in the movie Chappie **can actually feel** as shown in the beginning of his up bringing. Chappie can actually speak so if he could feel it, wouldn't he be howling in pain? Like any other creature that can feel pain?

So to sum it all up my question is **Was Chappie able to feel his arm being sawed off**

Comment: There are two questions here: Can he feel his arm being sawed off?  (Yes, if he didn't have sensors sufficient to that, he'd lack sufficient feedback to interact with the world).  And separately, is his feedback mechanism ("feel") one of pain in the right circumstances?  Probably not.  Pain is a primitive feedback mechanism for organisms unable to quantify and prioritize feedback.

Comment: ...spoilers in the title?

Comment: is that better @wearebob